# a section is not showing up on mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

One of the sections in my website is not showing up on mobile view. I did check inside woocommerce and php file, but everything looks good. I tried to override the section using !important but still the same. I also added a media query that targeting those elements, but it's still not working. This section is integrated with woocommerce, so, if any input for woocommerce, I really appreciate as well.

So, I might missed something in my scripts.

```js
jQuery('form.variations_form').on( 'show_variation', 
    function(event, variation){
      let output_date='';
      let scheduled_date_string = variation.scheduled_date;
      console.log(variation.scheduled_date);

      let button_text_original = 'Buy Online';
      let button_text_preorder = 'Pre-Order Now';

      if (!scheduled_date_string) {
        output_date= '7 - 10 Business Days';
        jQuery(this).find('button.button').html(button_text_original);
      }else{
        let current_date = new Date();
        let scheduled_date_parts = scheduled_date_string.split('/');/*date format must be in d/m/Y */
        let scheduled_date_year = parseInt(scheduled_date_parts[2].length<4 ? '20'+scheduled_date_parts[2]:scheduled_date_parts[2]);
        let scheduled_date_month = parseInt(scheduled_date_parts[1]) - 1;
        let scheduled_date_day = parseInt(scheduled_date_parts[0]);
        let scheduled_date = new Date(scheduled_date_year,scheduled_date_month,scheduled_date_day);
        console.log(scheduled_date);

        if (current_date >= scheduled_date) {
          output_date= '7 - 10 Business Days';
          jQuery(this).find('button.button').html(button_text_original);
        }else{
          output_date = scheduled_date_string;
          jQuery(this).find('button.button').html(button_text_preorder);
        }
      }

      if (jQuery('.shipping-date-container').length) {
        jQuery('.shipping-date-container').html('Estimated to leave our warehouse by: <span class="shipping-date">'+output_date+'</span>');
      }else if(jQuery('body.single-product .et_pb_wc_title').length){
        jQuery('body.single-product .et_pb_wc_title').after('<div class="shipping-date-container">Estimated to leave our warehouse by: <span class="shipping-date">'+output_date+'</span></div>');
      }

    } 
  );
```

```css
/* Estimated Shipping Date */
.shipping-date-container{
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #1e1919;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
span.shipping-date{
    color: #a13a18;
    font-weight: 600;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px){
  .shipping-date-container span.shipping-date{
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="shipping-date-container">
  Estimated shipping date: 
  <span class="shipping-date">31/07/2021</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Check in your console what the css-rule is set to (for element(s) not showing up). Woocommerce? then it might be som cache plugin etc that messes things up. Have you cleared cache?

Comment: ```One of the sections in my website is not showing up on mobile view``` Do you mean ```<div class="shipping-date-container">``` is not showing in your website?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld yes I did clear cache and checked the element in woocommerce, but still the same

Comment: @ikhvjs it's showing up on desktop view but it's invisible on mobile view. I want both to be visible

Comment: I don't believe you have identified the real problem. My guts tells it's a css rule in a theme somewhere or a custom css or such that overrides what you are trying to do. I would set the div-element(s) to inline-style display:block !important just to test if it works (or not). If that does not work (if it's still invisible then you'r probably in wrong template file and editing)

Comment: @tengkuzulfadli, which browser is used in the mobile view?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld I did set to inline style. But still the same. It might be somewhere in php, I guess?

Comment: @ikhvjs all browsers

Comment: @tengkuzulfadli - If you change the classname/remove the classnames in HTML. Is it still the same?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld I have just found it, it was somewhere inside jQuery file. I got confused whether to use jQuery or $ sign

Comment: @tengkuzulfadli - good. I'm not sure this question and answer will give any good clues to any other reader though. (even if you have found it). Congrats :-)

Answer (score 0):

There was a conflict in using jQuery or $ sign somewhere inside the same file. Where is in my jQuery script uses jQuery instead of $.